SPD 2010 workflow assigning task to Domain2 user instead of Domain1
I have a SPD 2010 workflow on SharePoint 2016. SharePoint is on Domain2 while users are connecting from Domain1.
SharePoint 2016 was originally running from Domain1 and it has been migrated to Domain2. After migration, problem is sometime it assigns task to user Domain2\user instead of Domain1\user. Because of this users are unable to update task (as users are still connecting from Domain1) as it is not assigned to them.
I am not sure if this is happening for all users but I have experienced it for some users. How do I make sure that task is always assigned to Domain1\user and not to Domain2\user?
